# Updating iTunes to 11.1.0 gives an error

Tags: itunes

I tried to download the iTunes 11.1 update and received the following error. Does anyone know what could be causing it?

> The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1102.)

Comment: Do you have a firewall in use?

Comment: Did you try to download directly from apple.com instead? I had similar issues when I used the update check from within iTunes

Comment: Apple site still has 11.05 not 11.1

Comment: Earlier today, I successfully downloaded iTunes 11.1 (126) from [here](http://www.apple.com/itunes/download/) _to an iMac_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's due to the overload on Apple's side relating to the launch of iOS 7 a few hours ago.

That part of the download infrastructure should scale up over time well - try again every 30 minutes or so.

Comment: Gotcha. I tried from the the download page this morning and everything worked.

Answer (score -1):

try now, it's working....it was overloaded i guess.